# ifuse ~/iphone/ stuck and now returning anything in the terminal

Tags: iphone, linux, ubuntu

I use the newest ubuntu version and am trying to connect my iphone 8 to my laptop via cable to extract some files. here are my installation steps so far:

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils
sudo apt-get install ifuse 
mkdir ~/iphone
mount your iphone
ifuse ~/iphone
```

then it's stuck at the last step, so when I click enter it just returns nothing, so by nothing I mean it doesn't execute, just stays pending.
So what could be wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: same issue, did you find a solution?